# Laravel BelongsToMany method returns nothing

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent, pivot-table

I am implementing a many-to-many relationship in Laravel.
The entities are:
`users`
`roles`
and pivot table `user_role`

```
Users
====
id
name
.....

roles
====
id
role
...

   user_role
   ======
   userId
   roleId
```

Trying various ways to get the `roles` of a `user` but no luck so far. Any ideas?

Last try is:

```
/**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_role', 'userId', 'roleId');
    }
```

Current output on Laravel Tinker:

```
>>> $user->roles()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany {#2380
     +withTimestamps: false,
```

Comment: what is your current error/output ?

Comment: Updated my question, @FarazIrfan

Comment: are you sure you are finding $user?

Comment: Yes, I am getting back the correct user. @ChiragPatel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$user->roles()` is just the query for the relationship, it is not executed

You can use

```
$user->roles
```

if you don't need to add extra conditions or

```
$user->roles()->where(your conditions)->get()
```

for a more complex relationship query.

The key difference is the usage of pharentesis: `->roles` vs `->roles()`. The former returns the query result, the latter the query itself

Comment: Incredible what I have been struggling with! :D Thanks, @gbalduzzi

Comment: I have been through the same struggle :D